# If there is no local minimum between any two variables of a multivariate function, then whether the entire function also has no local minimum.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

For a multivariate function, suppose it is a $3$-variable function $f(x,y,z)$.

If there is no local minimum on the $x-y$ plane, no local minimum on the $x-z$ plane, and no local minimum on the $y-z$ plane, then can it be stated that $f(x,y,z)$  has not local minimum?

Comment: No, that conditions does not ensure that the function has no minimum. Take for example $f(x,y,z)=(x+1)^2+(y-3)^2+(z+5)^2$ which is infinitely differentiable. Then you can calculate its gradient and observe that the only critical point is $(-1,3,-5)$ which is clearly a (global) minimum because $f$ is always positive and $f(-1,3,-5)=0$. Now, as it is the unique critical point no local minimum is located in any of the planes you suggested but the function still has one.

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is that this function has no local minima, not without the global minima. In other words, in this case, the function has only a global minimum.

Comment: A global minimum is also a local minimum.

Comment: I don’t understand, isn’t (-1, 3) a local minimum in the x-y plane?

Comment: Your function is a function from $\mathbb{R^3}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, you cannot evaluate it on a point in $\mathbb{R}^2$.